# Dr Brenner's intentions with Eleven

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

**Spoilers. Don't read if haven't seen *Stranger Things* season 1.**

In the first season, right from the starting, we are shown that **Dr. Brenner** is in search for **Eleven**. Apparently they were testing on her, which is shown multiple times further.

My question is **what was the motive of Brenner's in searching Eleven? What were his intentions?**

Because throughout the season we are shown that his search for her is very serious - involving secret team, killing people ruthlessly and as the show proceeds, it escalates to the level where cars filled with cops are shown.

Was it all just to cover his *experiment gone wrong*? Or to kill the monster? Or to use Eleven as a weapon?

Comment: I'm not sure if we yet have a well-stated inverse explaination, but I do think part of it was to hide his/the Lab's expiriments, but I also suspect that one could argue that because Eleven blew a hole open to the Upside Down Dimension that perhaps they were hoping she could also seal it off, which we learn at the end of season two, she is capable of.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What was the motive of Brenner's in searching Eleven?**

They were using Eleven to spy on a Russian agent, she was their asset. They did so much coverup to keep her with them, how can they let her go easily?

**Was it all just to cover his experiment gone wrong? Or to kill the monster? Or to use Eleven as a weapon?**

I don't think it was just only for coverup but also to get their asset/weapon back. They can still use Eleven for their dirty work. But of course they want to kill the monster too as it was harming their research and Eleven can be helpful in that.

Second season spoiler:

> Eleven did helped them in closing the other dimension hole.